# Reset Purchases with In-App Billing V3 (Android)

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I successfully implemented the in-app billing V3 and it works with my test account. I have two (real) non-consumable items and one I have purchased and discovered the bill in my Google checkout account. In my app the status of the purchased item is "purchased", the second is "not purchased" - as it should be.

Now I would like to reset this item to no purchased.
Already refund the money in Google checkout without any change (still purchased).

Or is that not possible?

Comment: do you mean you have returned money from developer console? If yes then next time when you send getPurchae() you should not get that product id in response.

Comment: I have returned money from google checkout. I would like to re-buy the same (real) product again with the same account (for testing on other devices).

Comment: Check the response after calling getPurchae() you should not get that product id in response.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this problem? I'm having the same issue.